# ListView Lack of Memory in Xamarin.Android while scrolling

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm quite new with Xamarin.Android, and I have been reading different sites and solutions, but most of them are in Java or they talked about some libraries that they don't have good documentation. My main problem is that from time to time while I'm scrolling the app, it crashes suddenly and is restarted, throwing a message of *Lack of Memory*. My current adapter has the following code:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
    var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DishesListItem, parent, false);

    var lblTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Title);
    var imgThumbnail = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Thumbnail);

    lblTitle.Text = data[position].name;

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open(data[position].image)))
        {
            Drawable d = Drawable.CreateFromStream(sr.BaseStream, null);
            imgThumbnail.SetImageDrawable(d);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        imgThumbnail = null;
    }

    return view;
}
```

I want to clarify that all my images are stored locally, I'm not downloading anything from the internet or accessing the SD Cards, pictures folders, etc. My images are located in the *Assets folder* because they are linked to a SQLite database and some IDs.

Currently, I'm just loading the Adapter once on the OnCreate method.

I found this solution, but it's not always working:
[Tips & Tricks for Highly Performing Android ListViews](https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/)

I notice that if you move from one Activity to another Activity and later you come back to the activity where is the ListView and you start scrolling up and down, it just crashes again.

Does anyone have experienced it before? And if you have, do you have a recommendation what can I change?

Comment: you should not inflate new view each time. You need to reuse `convertView`, if it is not null. That's why you run out of memory

Comment: I tried this solution and it partially works:
https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/

Comment: Did you inspect your memory leaks? You can use [Android Studio to inspect and analyse your heap dumps](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html#hdanalyze)

Comment: Currently, I'm just testing in my device and I noticed this: if you move from one Activity to another Activity and later you come back to the activity where is the ListView and you start scrolling up and down, it just crashes again.

Comment: You could also implement the view holder pattern, or switch to using a RecyclerView. Calling FindViewById is an expensive performance call. Calling it 2 times for every single row when the user scrolls can kill performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After my research has provided a successful result, I want to share my solution and I hope is going to help many developers in the near future. I consider these comments can be useful in *C#* and perhaps Java.

**1)** To design a extremely simple *holder class* is important, but it's not enough.

```
    private class MyViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView lblTitle { get; set; }
        public ImageView imgThumbnail { get; set; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
        MyViewHolder holder = null;
        var view = convertView;

        if (view != null)
            holder = view.Tag as MyViewHolder;

        if (holder == null)
        {
            holder = new MyViewHolder();
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DishesListItem, parent, false);
            holder.lblTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Title);
            holder.imgThumbnail = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Thumbnail);
            view.Tag = holder;
        }

        holder.lblTitle.Text = data[position].name;

        try
        {
            holder.imgThumbnail.SetImageDrawable(data[position].image);
        }
        catch
        {
            holder.imgThumbnail = null;
        }

        return view;
    }
```

**2)** You need to send a very simple class to the adapter just with the information to load. You should not send more or less information if you do it, there is going to be a new lack of memory.

```
public class CompactedData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Drawable image { get; set; }
}
```

**3)** My instinct told me that I should optimize the class more and I need to stop loading any image in the Adapter, if you do that the holder is going to be sort of inefficient and it was true; the adapter was not good enough, you need to pre-load all images that you are going to add to the holder class if you want the maximum efficiency.

This section of code is the most inefficient in my experience and sooner or later is going to create a new lack of memory.

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open(data[position].image)))
    {
        using (var d = Drawable.CreateFromStream(sr.BaseStream, null))
        {
            imgThumbnail.SetImageDrawable(d);
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    imgThumbnail = null;
}
```

This point is not going to be different if your images are local or not, you **must** pre-load it in the class that you're sharing to the **Adapter** before (in my case was called data).

**Edit:**
You can add the code to dispose the variables too as Skall suggested.

```
    List<CompactedData> data;

    public PreviewDishesAdapter(List<CompactedData> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
```

**4)** Finally, if your App is going to use several times the same Adapter or a similar one with images, this code is **vital** in the every activity in order to avoid any possible crash:

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
        GC.Collect();
        Finish();
    }
```

You **must** execute the *Garbage Collector* and *Finish* the *Activity*, if you keep it open there is going to be a new ***Lack of Memory*** at any point.

If most of us consider all these points, we can avoid using a *Large Heap* or modify other points that Google doesn't recommend, which are very common suggestions in similar topics.

*A final thought, if you're going to have a large bunch of images, it's a good idea to create some **Thumbnails** in order to reduce the loading of the ListView, this will allow you to load more data without many problems because even the RecyclerView could produce lacks of memory; especially if you're working with **Tabs** or different **Fragments** because you cannot predict effectively when or how to execute the Garbage Collector.*

You can create them easily with some Apps like [ImageResizer](http://bricelam.net/ImageResizer), you're going to avoid unnecessary headaches with a couple of clicks.

Comment: This might work for your set of data but I would not suggest preloading the  drawables. What if the dataset is 10k items? What would happen then? #3 is creating a memory leak and I believe my answer below would address the issue. Memory management in C# is a little more trickier than in Java as you have 2 VM's to think about. The drawable object lives in the Dalvik VM or ART, not on Mono VM, and not disposing it would create a memory leak. Removing the GC.Collect from your code and fixing the leaks IMO would give valuable info about this.

Comment: When I didn't force the GC crashed again too. That's why I added it and it perfectly worked without extending the heap. By the way you can see that when I'm forcing the GC and finishing the Activity, I'm realising the unnecessary resources.

Comment: What I am saying is the GC is not the best solution to deal with this. You would be better off finding the real issue.

Comment: Based on several experiments in another app which the GC didn't work as in this one. I concluded that one of the reasons is the amount of images and the best approach was to create some thumbnails which increased the performance significantly because I still tested the RecyclerView and by itself was not the best solution.

Comment: Did you test disposing the drawable (with using() statement) as I suggested? Run both versions with Android Device Monitor running to see if there is a big difference in memory allocations. This probably doesn't affect performance significantly.

Comment: Hi, yes, I did it, but because I'm not loading the images in the adapter anymore, I didn't see any major change, the Thumbnails impacted significantly.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem especially when scrolling the listview fast, what we did aside from optimizing our listView is to add this application setting:

```
[Application(LargeHeap = true)]
```

above the MainApplication.cs:

```
//You can specify additional application information in this attribute
    [Application(LargeHeap = true)]
    public class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
    { ...
```

What it does: If true, then the process should be created with a large Dalvik heap; otherwise, the process will be created with the default Dalvik heap.

You can also set this in your  AndroidManifest.xml.

```
 <application android:label="YourAppName" android:largeHeap="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon"></application>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I already found a solution and I shared it. Besides, I read in many places that we should not do this, I talked about it in my personal answer. I consider using a LargeHeap, we are only delaying a future lack of memory and that is not going to work in some devices with few resources.

Answer (score 2):

With Android images you have to be very careful. I have not tested this but there is a possibility the drawable is creating a memory leak. You could try if this one is of any help:

```
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open(data[position].image)))
        {
            using (var d = Drawable.CreateFromStream(sr.BaseStream, null))
            {
                imgThumbnail.SetImageDrawable(d);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already explained that in my personal answer and you're right, but there are many things that you need to consider in my experience.